# Elegant way to wrap container methods in javascript for Redux

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

My mapDispatchToProps method after creating a separate file* with all the relevant methods is:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {

    return {
        toggleTreeMode: () =>           {dispatch(editor_thunks.toggleTreeMode());},
        toggleDrawer: (e) =>            {dispatch(editor_thunks.toggleDrawer(e));},
        toggleDataButtons: (on) =>      {dispatch(editor_thunks.toggleDataButtons(on));},
        //... many more methods
}
```

The signatures are all the same so it feels like there must be a better in ES6 to wrap this. Is there?

This won't work as I need the dispatch:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {

    return editor_thunks;
}
```

*most of the methods needed the state so it felt like the best solution

Comment: Maybe better to use `bindactioncreators` (http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html ) to avoid copy-paste code in map-dispatch functions for containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mapDispatchToProps()` Shorthand Notation. Instead of a function the parameter `mapDispatchToProps` can be a configuration object. According to the [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments):

> **[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps]** (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is
>   assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function
>   names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so
>   they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s
>   props.

This means that if you just need to wrap all action with dispatch, you can pass an object of method, and each method in the object will be wrapped in `dispatch` automatically.

**If you need some actions from editor_thunks**

```
const { toggleTreeMode, toggleDrawer, toggleDataButtons } = editor_thunks; 

connect(mapStateToProps, { toggleTreeMode, toggleDrawer, toggleDataButtons })(Component);
```

**If you need all actions from editor_thunks**

```
connect(mapStateToProps, editor_thunks)(Component);
```